# Getting a string result from XPath expression in Talend cSetHeader

Tags: apache-camel, talend

I'm being stumped by something that should be trivial.

I've got an xml document, which is split using cSplitter using XPath which works fine, but then I want to set headers with values from the split document.

I've got a cSetHeader component with the Language set to XPath and the valid xpath. However, it returns the value as a NodeList object, when I need a string.

If I use an XPath expression that returns a string, it gives an exception as it can't convert to NodeList.

How, in Talend, do I configure the XPath expression to return a string. It seems ok if you're writing the camel directly, as there is a parameter, but I can't see how it is done in Talend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out...

As it's a code generator, talend puts in the `.xpath( ... )` whatever you type in the field - so if you want it to generate a string you put

```
"/your/xpath/here", java.lang.String.class
```

in the `cSetHeader` xpath field and the code generator puts your xpath string with the requested class in the right place!

Easy! Now why didn't I think of that earlier...?